# Thousand separator without precision in C#

Tags: c#, number-formatting

Simply I'm looking for a way in which to return an integer to thousand separated string format without precisions.

I tried different format specifier but all of them get me 2 digit precisions .

For instances I would like

```
123456  => "123,456" and not "123,456,00"
```

or

```
1234567 => "1,234,567"
```

and not `"1,234,567.00"`

Comment: Please specify which format specifiers you tried.

Comment: The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier.:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify a precision of 0 like this when using the [standard numeric format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString) of "n":

```
string text = value.ToString("n0");
```

Or in [composite form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx#CompositeFormatting):

```
Console.WriteLine("The number is {0:n0}", value);
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
int myNumber = 1234567;

var myString = myNumber.ToString("n0");
```